# How do I use GLMath in an xcode project?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, xcode4.6

[this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1) leads me to believe I can leverage GLMath from my xcode project.

Quote:

> GLMath. Prior to iOS 5, pretty much every game needed their own math
>   library with common vector and matrix manipulation routines. Now with
>   GLMath, most of the common math routines are there for you!

I've searched a bit but can't find how to link this all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you include the GLKit framework in your project (check your project settings under build phases -> link binary with...) you can get it by importing `<GLKit/GLKMath.h>` but if you import `<GLKit/GLKit.h>` you will get it anyway

Comment: I thought that would have been the case. I was clumsy with finding the API calls. GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt was what I was looking for. Really didn't feel like writing my own for no reason. Thanks.